# Variable assigned to button click function not reflected in API

Tags: javascript, weather-api

I have two buttons to toggle between cities for a weather API.

When I assign the variable to be determined by button click:

```
TButton.addEventListener("click", TWeather);

function TWeather(){
    outputDiv.style.display = "block";
    const buttonCity = "Toronto";
};
```

the URL for the API won't recognize it.

```
    const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + buttonCity + "&appid=" + myAPIkey + "&units=metric";
```

It works if I set the variable outside of the button function.

Comment: "I have two buttons to toggle between cities for a weather API."  It might help to actually see the HTML markup here (a set of code that actually reproduces this issue) so we can best help you with a solution vs "suggestions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to put your xhr.open and send inside your two button functions. Remember the url for the xhr.open should assign the location. Hope this works. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think that const is a local variable not a global one.
Define your variable after the addEventListener outside the function and give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are defining the buttonCity variable in the TWeather function so that variable is only available in the scope of that function. Please read the following: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

You will have to assign this variable where it is accessible to the other function as well.

Example:

```
let currentCity = '';

TButton.addEventListener("click", TWeather);

function TWeather(){
    outputDiv.style.display = "block";
    currentCity = "Toronto";
};
```

And then API CALL:

```
const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + currentCity + "&appid=" + myAPIkey + "&units=metric";
```

Comment: A global variable is most often NOT the best solution

Comment: I do not recommend it either. But seeing we don't have the scope of the project it's the only sure-fire way that he will get it to work. I suggest having it in the correct scope of possible.

Comment: That is true, but it actually answers the question and solves the problem. The "Use of Global Variables" is another title, but it must be mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what you wanted to do with the URL so I just did a `console.log`.

Here I create a object and add some properties including some functions to add the event handler.  I also added the target city to each button as a data attribute, then pulled that out within the event handler.

This is a bit overkill perhaps but does illustrate some ways to avoid global variables and make it so you can add more buttons to the HTML without any code changes.

```js
var myapp = {
  url: {
    base: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=",
    api: "&appid=",
    unit: "&units=metric"
  },
  apiKey = "key",
  baseSelector:".weather-toggle",
  buttons: {},
  init: function() {
    const app = this;
    this.buttons = document.querySelectorAll(this.baseSelector);
    this.buttons.forEach(function(button, index, buttons) {
      button.addEventListener("click", this.toggleWeather, false);
    },this);
  },
  toggleWeather: function(event) {
    const targetCity = event.target.dataset.targetCity;
    const url = myapp.url.base + targetCity + myapp.url.api + myapp.apiKey + myapp.url.unit;
    console.log(url);
  }
};

myapp.init.apply(myapp);
```

```html
<button class="weather-toggle" type="button" data-target-city="Toronto">Toronto</button>
<button class="weather-toggle" type="button" data-target-city="NewYork">New York City</button>
<button class="weather-toggle" type="button" data-target-city="Boston">Boston</button>
```